Topological equivalence of Feynman diagrams
I am working on a task and needed to look at different Feynman diagrams for scalar fields (so bosons). I came across these two and I remember my lecturer saying that these are the same because we are working with bosons. But I do not see why. Any help would be greatly appreciated!



The two are related by interchanging the external states with momenta $k_3$ and $k_4$. States of bosons are symmetric under such exchange while states of fermions are anti-symmetric.

@Gold how does this lead to being topologicaly equivalent?

@RoITF73 What kind of proof or explanation are you looking for with respect to the two diagrams being topologically equivalent? The two diagrams are related via a crossing symmetry, but in your diagrams, what is the direction of time, bottom to top or left to right? Also, if this is $\lambda\phi^3$ theory, should there not be three diagrams, $s$, $t$, and $u$?
